# How to execute keyboard shortcut via .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I am trying to open the On-Screen Keyboard (`WIN` + `CTRL` + `O`) by clicking on a .bat file.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is as simple as this. Just three simple letters.

```
OSK
```

The full executable path to the file is: C:\Windows\System32\osk.exe

Comment: Perfect, Thank you!